# Remove multiple elements from array and reindex

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, array-unset

Can I remove the first three elements and all the remaining ones where `value` is not equal to 2? The language is php.

```
print_r($array)
```

outputs

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [name] => aa [value] => 0 )        
    [1] => Array ( [name] => db [value] => 1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [name] => bc [value] => 2 )
    [3] => Array ( [name] => ba [value] => 3 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [name] => ba [value] => 0 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [name] => bc [value] => 1 )    
    [6] => Array ( [name] => aa [value] => 2 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [name] => cb [value] => 3 )
    [8] => Array ( [name] => ca [value] => 0 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [name] => dc [value] => 1 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [name] => db [value] => 2 )
    [11] => Array ( [name] => aa [value] => 3 )
    [12] => Array ( [name] => dd [value] => 0 )
    [13] => Array ( [name] => db [value] => 1 )
    [14] => Array ( [name] => bb [value] => 2 )
    [15] => Array ( [name] => ac [value] => 3 )
)
```

I also need to reindex so that it begins from 0

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [name] => aa [value] => 2 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [name] => db [value] => 2 )
    [2] => Array ( [name] => bb [value] => 2 )
)
```

Comment: It would depend on the language.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to write some code to do it.  Try something and tell us how it goes, and if it doesn't work, then we can help.

Comment: Is it always the first three elements? Or just remove those that don't have a value of `2`?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes, the first three elements should always be destroyed no matter what, and from the fourth one only those which value is 2 should be kept.

Comment: @AndyLester. Thanks, I have tried to unset the elements with a foreach loop, but couldn't work it out how to unset more than one element at once.

Comment: While it doesn't meet your exact requirements, I encourage future readers to look at [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Thanks, that is a useful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do do it this way:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if ($k > 2 && $v['value'] == 2) {
        $new_array[] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: That will copy items where `$v['value']` is equal to `2`. If you want to remove  those items (as I understand the question), it's `!=`

Comment: It's the other way around, I want to remove the values which are not equal to `2`. I wasn't clear enough. You helped me to understand this really well. If `value` is buried deeper in `parent` array,  `if ($k > 2 and $v['parent'] ['value'] == 2)` works as well.